# C# ASPX - Form Submission Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a C# aspx form in which I need to input it's data into an SQL database and then return a response saying successful or not. I have no idea how to get the form data that is sent from the Default.aspx page. My basic code structure is below:

**Default.aspx**

```
<form runat="server" name="aForm" action="Results.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="ValidateForm()">  
  <input name="firstname" type="text" />
  <input name="surname" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Results.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class AwardsForm : System.Web.UI.Page {

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if (!this.IsPostBack){
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    } else (this.IsPostBack) {
        writeResults(FormSubmit()); 
    }

    protected boolean FormSubmit() {
      // get form data and insert it into SQL
      // return true/false based on success
    }

    protected void writeResults(boolean results) {
      if (results == true) {
        Response.Write ("Success");
      } else {
        Response.Write ("Failed");
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the posted form data through `Request.Form["key"]`, or, if your form elements are decorated with `runat="server"` then you should be able to grab them by id right in your code behind

```
<asp:TextBox id="yourTb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

string postedText = yourTb.Text;
```

Or you can do (though this is much less common)

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="yourOtherTb" />

string otherPostedText = yourOtherTb.Value;
```

Or if you're working with purely html form inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="clientTb" name="clientTb" />

string clientText = Request.Form["clientTb"];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, looks good to me. Any idea about this machine key business? This is a local form and won't be used online.
I have tried to no prevail to do the steps taken here: http://sharemypoint.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/machinekey-in-webconfig/.

Comment: Not sure about the machine key thing @Bonjour - sorry

Comment: No problem, I got it to work using the hack on the page. Thanks for your answer mate, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by the following code.

```
string firstname = Request.Form["firstname"]

string surname = Request.Form["surname"]
```

Comment: Thankyou mate, this answer is good. If you have any input on my reply to Adam's answer above, that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing something like this

```
 <input name="firstname" type="text" />
  <input name="surname" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

the `name` attribute of the input controls are posted back to the server(IIS). Hence you would do this.

```
If(IsPostBack)
{
  string firstName = Request.Form["firstname"];
  string surName = Request.Form["surname"];

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
{
Response.Write("Firstname is required this form");
}
}
```

Comment: Thankyou mate, this answer is good. If you have any input on my reply to Adam's answer above, that would be great thanks.

Comment: @Bonjour http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx Machine key is used for encryption and decryption of form data when posting to other applications in same domain. Your requirement does not need one, Please do remove the `<machinekey>` section from the web.config